# How to sort this array by priority

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a class that sets values to $this->properties inside an attach method.
I'll shorten the code here for the sake of simplicity:

```
<?php
class Event
{
    protected $properties = array();

    public function attach( $event_name, $context, $event, $callback, $priority )
    {
         $this->properties [$event_name] = array(
                $context,
                $event,
                $callback,
                $priority,
        );
    }

    public function dispatchAll( $context = '0' )
    {
         foreach( $this->properties as $p ) {
            if( $p[0] == $context ) {
                $this->dispatch( $p[1] );
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    public function dispath( $event_name ) 
    {
        // implentation not necessary for this question
    }
}
```

What I need is to sort `$this->properties` by "context,priority" so that I can run the code matching the context of my application in ascendent order.

Bellow the `var_dump` of just 3 set properties:

```
array(3) {
  ["StartUp"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "StartUp"
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Bootstrap"
      [1]=>
      string(7) "startup"
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        int(1)
        [1]=>
        object(Event)#6 (4) {
          ["name":protected]=>
          NULL
          ["target":protected]=>
          NULL
          ["parameters":protected]=>
          *RECURSION*
          ["result":protected]=>
          NULL
        }
      }
    }
    [3]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["View"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "View"
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Bootstrap"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "view"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(Event)#6 (4) {
        ["name":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["target":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["parameters":protected]=>
        *RECURSION*
        ["result":protected]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
  ["ShutDown"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "ShutDown"
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Bootstrap"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "shutdown"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(Event)#6 (4) {
        ["name":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["target":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["parameters":protected]=>
        *RECURSION*
        ["result":protected]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a dump of `$properties`?

Comment: I've included the var_dump along side the question

Answer (score 0):

[usort()](https://www.php.net/usort) lets you sort an array by a user-specified function.

Alternatively, if the array is populated from a database then you can always use ORDER BY in the query to get the elements back in the order you want.

Comment: I have already tried usort() but with no success... in fact with a lot of other variations. That's why I posted the above title... 'Cos they were a lot of tries... I feel like I'm a newbie... hehehe